# Tattoo phrase translated properly!

Tags: phrase-requests, british-english

I’m Spanish and I wanna get tattooed a phrase that I always say but in English instead. It’s something like ‘You can’t judge someone for something he hasn’t chosen’ 
I know it is not right like that, that’s why I want to find the right way to say it. 
E.g 
A person has a big nose and there is this guy always laughing at her because of that. That person was born like that, is not something that she could choose

The father of a kid is an alcoholic, but that doesn’t mean he is going to be an alcoholic too when he is older.

I don’t know if it’s a bit more clear now!

Thanks anyway

Comment: My sincere advice: never, ever get a tattoo in another language if you need to ask a question like this.

Comment: I agree with Cascabel. Why not just write it in Spanish?

Comment: https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-05/26/12/enhanced/webdr05/enhanced-buzz-7651-1432657116-34.jpg?downsize=700%3A%2A&output-quality=auto&output-format=auto

Answer (score -3):

**Don't judge a book by its cover.** (Or *You can't judge a book by its cover*.)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_judge_a_book_by_its_cover):

> The English idiom "don't judge a book by its cover" is a metaphorical phrase which means "you shouldn't prejudge the worth or value of something by its outward appearance alone". For example "That man may look very small and insignificant, but don't judge a book by its cover – he's a very powerful man in his circle"

---

But I give the same caution as a comment under your question. Don't take my word for this idiom. Look it up online and see the examples of its use. Make sure it really is something you want to use. (Assuming there isn't another answer that you like more.)

**Update**: In response to a comment, the idiom *is* metaphorical, which means it can cover not just physical appearances but also assumptions in general. It doesn't need to apply merely to things that are visual.

Comment: I think that phrase is making a different point to the one that Carla wants. That says, don't judge by what you can see, but the original question goes further and says, Don't judge by even what you can't see, when the person never had a chance to be any different.

Comment: I think this one is perfect, thank you so much!! x

Answer (score -3):

“Life is a matter of choices, and every choice you make makes you.” —John C. Maxwell

I have a lot of tattoos, personally I like ones that create conversation. Looking at your scenario about the alcoholic farther then Mark Twain has a quote that fits:

Climate is what we expect, weather is what we get.

What this translates to is that because climate is based on patterns and predictions of what has happened in the past that is what we expect, however, life/nature/people have choices.